# How does one get the front-most layer instead of the deepest layer using HitTest

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, calayer, hittest

Well, I just wasted 2 days on that.
Simplest example : I have  2 UIView's who's being **animated** from the top of the screen to the bottom. After a lot of researching i found out that the only way you can "touch/trigger" touch event when UIView is being animated , is via HitTest using presentationLayer property.

**Inside touchBegan method**

```
    x as! UIView

   if x.layer.presentationLayer()!.hitTest(touchlocation) != nil {
    x.alpha = 0
    //Layer touched
    }
```

**Situation :**
During the animation,the first UIView overlaps\upon the second UIView. At that point i'm "touching" the topest UIView.
**Problem :** HitTest return the lowest\deepest layer , So the bottom UIView layer will be the recognized one.
**Question : How do i get the first/frontmost UIView layer instead of the deepest?**

Comment: Can you describe the variable `x` in this context? Is `x` the containing `UIViewController`'s `view` or does `x` represent the view being animated?

Comment: x is view being animated. You have UIView X and UIView Y. Both being animated(UIVIew.animationDuration etc). While being animated X goes Above Y. Meaning that X is over the top and Y behind him. I'm clicking the top UIView - X. Inside the TouchBegan method(as described above) im trying to detect the touch using hitTest . HitTest trigger the deepest layer in the given location - Which means UIView Y is being recongized instead of X. How do i get recongize of the topest animated UIVIew X? @ThuggishNuggets

Comment: According to the [`hitTest` Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/hitTest:) it should only be exhibiting the behavior you describe if one of the layers representing view `y` is a member of the `x.sublayers` collection/array, as `hitTest` traverses the layer hierarchy starting with the receiver. If `x` and `y` are _siblings with a common superlayer_ this should not be possible unless the animation is mucking with their layers' hierarchy in some way.

Comment: @ThuggishNuggets Hmm like i thought so..So there isnt a way to detect touch on a animated UIView if both another animated UIView x/y collapses?

Comment: Add a breakpoint to your touchBegan and check to see if `x.presentationLayer().superlayer` and `y.presentationLayer().superlayer` are the same layer instance. If they are truly sibling layers I think they should have the same superlayer.

Comment: @ThuggishNuggets I'm sorry for the my ignorance but i'm having hard time understanding what you meant , Can you please create a chat? More dynamiac

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92319/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-thuggish-nuggets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [our chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92319/discussion-between-roi-mulia-and-thuggish-nuggets) we found out what was actually happening.

Basically, to detect the touches, you were iterating over all the subviews in the view controller and performing a `hitTest` on each of their `presentationLayer`s to detect the touch *during an animation*.

**There were a few problems we discovered:**

1. `hitTest` was returning a sublayer of the current subview's (`x`) layer and was unknowingly being conflated with another view (`y`).
2. The `for` loop used to iterate over the subviews wasn't utilizing the `break` statement once it found its target, resulting in the confusion in `1` above.
3. By iterating over the subviews in normal order, the views were being searched back-to-front because of the way that `addSubview` and `subviews` are structured.

**Solution**

Ultimately the solution came from fixing these issues by:

- Iterating over the subviews in reverse order using `for x in self.view.subviews.reverse()`
- Testing to see if the layer returned by `hitTest` was a sublayer of
  the current view that was being tested (pseudo-code) `if layerThatWasHit.superlayer == x.presentationLayer()`
- Adding the `break` statement inside of the `if` where the view hit was
  detected to terminate the `for` loop and prevent multiple executions
  of the code that results in a tap on one of the animated views.

Comment: Perfect. Just perfect, Thanks buddy!